# How to Handel Map In android using Kotlin

Tags: android, dictionary, kotlin

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
}
```

}

Comment: The code you post is not relevant to the question. Please make it more specific.

Comment: give more specific code and explanation

Comment: Where is said "Map" code

Answer (score 0):

```
//Read only map

val map = mapOf("a" to 1, "b" to 2, "c" to 3)

//Accessing a map

println(map["key"])
map["key"] = value

//Traversing a map/list of pairs

for ((k, v) in map) {
    println("$k -> $v")
}
```